# How to dynamically set a topic publication for a model sensor?

Tags: gazebo, sensors, ros-humble, gazebo-sensor

I've got a Gazebo model defined in a SDF file that I spawn in my world with *ros_gz_sim create*, with the *-name* argument.
This allows me to spawn several models based on the same SDF file.
Now I added a sensor "*type='gpu_lidar'*", this sensor needs a topic to publish data to.

How can I alter this topic to still be able to spawn several models ?
maybe with the '-param' argument but I didn't find an example of how to use it.

(This is a Ros2 question as I want to implement the answer in my launch file.)

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing here can be accomplished with topic remapping. You can find documentation on it [here](http://design.ros2.org/articles/static_remapping.html), and another question about this topic [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/376720/how-to-remap-topic-in-a-ros2-launch-file/).

The basic concept behind topic remapping is to take two nodes that have the same topic (for example, two LIDAR nodes both publishing to `/lidar`) and change the name of the topic they operate under (so one goes to `/lidar_a` and another goes to `/lidar_b`).

This can be accomplished using launch files. Here's an example provided by the [turtlesim launch demo](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Creating-Launch-Files.html)s:

```py
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='turtlesim',
            namespace='turtlesim1',
            executable='turtlesim_node',
            name='sim'
        ),
        Node(
            package='turtlesim',
            namespace='turtlesim2',
            executable='turtlesim_node',
            name='sim'
        ),
        Node(
            package='turtlesim',
            executable='mimic',
            name='mimic',
            remappings=[
                ('/input/pose', '/turtlesim1/turtle1/pose'),
                ('/output/cmd_vel', '/turtlesim2/turtle1/cmd_vel'),
            ]
        )
    ])
```

Note the 'remappings' entry found in the bottom node: this is remapping the '/input/pose' topic to 'turtlesim1/turtle1/pose', etc.

Comment: If this works I don't known how to.
I used the remappings arg, or a remapping bridge file, but there still is only one gazebo topic redirected to several ros2 topic.

Comment: @cst0 your answer describes ROS2 remapping. The OP's question is about the topic of a Gazebo Sim System, i.e. a topic for `gz-transport`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to fix my pb is to remove the *topic* tag from the SDF file. This makes gazebo generates topics named */world/{{ WORLD_NAME }}/model/{{ drone_name }}/link/lidar_link/sensor/gpu_lidar/scan/points*.

With those unique topics I can remap them with a dynamically generated bridge file.